# Saving multiple objects for an attribute in CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

CoreData Structure:
[Entity: ZooAnimals, Attributes: animal (String type) and count (Integer 16 type)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3ty.png)

I want to save in some animal names and the quantity (count) of each animal. I can do this by hard coding the multiple objects needed to do this – see code below – but how could I do it more flexibly so that I might just give it a couple of arrays of any length and have them save into CoreData (e.g. `var animalArray = ["Donkey","Horse","Zebra","Okapi"], var animalCountArray = [7,3,9,2]`)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let animal1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ZooAnimals", into: managedContext)
        let animal2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ZooAnimals", into: managedContext)
        let animal3 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ZooAnimals", into: managedContext)
        let animal4 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ZooAnimals", into: managedContext)

        animal1.setValue("Donkey", forKey: "animal")
        animal1.setValue(7, forKey: "count")
        animal2.setValue("Horse", forKey: "animal")
        animal2.setValue(3, forKey: "count")
        animal3.setValue("Zebra", forKey: "animal")
        animal3.setValue(9, forKey: "count")
        animal4.setValue("Okapi", forKey: "animal")
        animal4.setValue(2, forKey: "count")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying this answer and I couldn't get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36194727/9684364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is a `for` loop

```
let animalArray = ["Donkey","Horse","Zebra","Okapi"]
let animalCountArray = [7,3,9,2]
assert(animalArray.count == animalCountArray.count, "The number of items in the arrays must be equal")

for i in 0..<animalArray.count {
    let animal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "ZooAnimals", into: managedContext)
    animal.setValue(animalArray[i], forKey: "animal")
    animal.setValue(animalCountArray[i], forKey: "count")
}
do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch  {
    print("Could not save. \(error)")
}
```

Side note: `guard`ing `AppDelegate` is pointless. The app wouldn't even launch if the application delegate class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to use a for loop

```
let employeeNames = ["Donkey", "Horse", "Zebra","Okapi"]
    for i in 0..<employeeNames.count
    {
        let employeeEntry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ZooAnimals", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject)

        employeeEntry.setValue(employeeNames[i], forKey: "employeename")
        employees.setValue(index, forKey: "animal")

        do {
            try managedObject.save()
        } catch {
            print("problem saving")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too, even though it is a bit unusual to name your employee after a zoo animal :)